# How do I include django URL in AJAX GET request and get JSON data?

Tags: django, json, jquery

I am running a development server and calling a template view to show me content of "index.html" on my browser.
Now I have a button configured in the index.htm file (using JQUERY) to do AJAX get request. How do I include the Django url to do this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
//alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
//alert("Text: " );


$.ajax({
url: 'application.json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data ) {
  alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
},
error: function( data ) {
  alert( "ERROR  " + data );
}
});
```

I want to replace the 'application.json' with a django url which would return me a json response.

here is the return values asscociated with the django view correspoing to the url I wan to include:

```
response = Response(200, result)
return self.render(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: {% url 'name-of-your-reverted url' %}
...
```

You can also use view path, just as in doc:
[Django Doc#url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: why do i have to include the "inverted" url ?
I am currently using the absolute path and it seems to work fine!
Absolute Path:
"http://......."

Comment: Yep, you can, and also put in this tag your view. By this way I wrote you can be sure that if you change website or your django url, it will reflect rightly on this file too.